# meaning of message.obj [android network]

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to understand this code:
and what i don't understand is

the `obj` from 
message.obj = result;

by the google api,
it is an arbitrary object to send to the recipient.
why are we using arbitrary object in this java[android] world???

```
class DownThread extends Thread {
    String mAddr;

    DownThread(String addr) {
        mAddr = addr;
    }

    public void run() {
        String result = DownloadHtml(mAddr);
        Message message = mAfterDown.obtainMessage();
        message.obj = result;
        mAfterDown.sendMessage(message);

    }

    String DownloadHtml(String addr) {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(addr);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream())
                    );
                    for(;;) {
                        String line = br.readLine();
                        if (line == null) break;
                        html.append(line + "/n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                }
                conn.disconnect();

            }
        } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
            return e.getMessage();

        } catch (Exception e){
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return html.toString();
    }

}


Handler mAfterDown = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mProgress.dismiss();
        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        result.setText((String) msg.obj);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#obj) says:

> An arbitrary object to send to the recipient.

Because Android does not know exactly what type of object in the `Message` to send.

In your code: `message.obj = result;` the `obj` has String type. But in other context, other type of object may be assigned.

Comment: Thank you, you've helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Handler is the mechanism being used to pass data between threads.  Handler will only let you schedule Message objects or Runnables to be executed on the thread that's processing the Handler.

You can't send any old object to sendMessage() because it will only take a Message typed object, so they're using the obj field within Message to contain the data to send.